# IllegalStateException when applying arguments to a fragment after a network response

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-networking

I'm getting an `IllegalStateException` error when I'm trying to add arguments to a `fragment` after a network call has completed. The crash happens while the network is doing a call and hasn't completed yet (slow networks) and you take the activity into the background (Say switching activities for example)

I need to pass data that comes from the network call to the `fragment` (List of urls that will populate a pageradapter for scrolling images.

My Code:

```
`onResume` I do the network call by calling `doWebserviceCall();`
```

After network call I call this method:

```
  private void configureImageScroller() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    // Boolean to hide the thumbnails when the Scrolling images is embedded in the item activity
    bundle.putBoolean(ScrollingTradeImagesFragment.INTENT_BOOL_EMBEDDED, false);
    // Pass the object to the Scrolling images fragment
    bundle.putParcelable(INTENT_KEY_TRADE_OBJECT, Parcels.wrap(mTradeItem));
    ScrollingTradeImagesFragment fragment = new ScrollingTradeImagesFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    //-------Crash happens here-------//
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.scrollable_image_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }
```

method that is run when network call is complete:

```
      @Override
  public void populateItemViews(final TradeItem aTradeItem) {
    mTradeItem = aTradeItem;
    // Do some stuff here that is irrelevant
    configureImageScroller();
    // Do some other stuff here that is irrelevant
  }
```

Whats the best way to do this to prevent this crash?

**EDIT:**

Stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1493)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1511)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:638)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:617)
   at com.bidorbuy.app.item.ItemActivity.configureImageScroller(ItemActivity.java:112)
   at com.bidorbuy.app.item.ItemActivity.populateItemViews(ItemActivity.java:233)
   at com.bidorbuy.app.item.ItemPresenter.handleNetworkResponse(ItemPresenter.java:37)
   at com.bidorbuy.app.network.NetworkManager$3.onResponse(NetworkManager.java:422)
   at com.bidorbuy.app.network.NetworkManager$3.onResponse(NetworkManager.java:419)
   at com.bidorbuy.app.network.volley.BobeRequest.deliverResponse(BobeRequest.java:127)
   at com.bidorbuy.app.network.volley.BobeRequest.deliverResponse(BobeRequest.java:26)
   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Comment: What's the stack trace say?

Comment: @MikeM. please see edit

Comment: I think main point of this is that you not canceling you call. If you run network call in OnResume, please, cancel it in onPause. Do you cancel call in `onPause` method?

Comment: You see it happens because you left your activity and it was stopped and probably destroyed. And then you recieve a network answer and thus calling `configureImageScroller()` for inconsistent state of Activity.

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin thanks , its kind of difficult to reproduce but I will try this. Please set this as an answer and if it works i will mark it as correct

Comment: @x10sion it's kind to difficult to reproduce because it not so simple to catch it. That's why you need to always be on the alert, when you work with multithreading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that you have not canceling a request. In your case it should be `onPause` method. Avoiding to do it you can bring at least to main errors to your code:

- Running in parrallel to or more same requests. For example if you run request in onResume and have not good network connection and then exit/return to application (by pressing home button), you will have multiple same requests running since onResume will be called several times and each request takes some time.
- Running "onComplete" callback in inconsistent state of `Activity` (or any other component like `Fragment`). Suppose you ran your request in `onResume` and then exit from application. `onPause` and `onStop` are invoked. `onSaveInstanceState` invoke and probably `onDestroy` too. Then your request gives success answer and you try to run some fragment for activity that was alredy stopped and saved. Thus, you have a exception.

**How to solve it**
You need just to cancel your request in onPause. Eventually, if you exit from application before callback will be invoked you will prevent invokation in inconsistent state. And also will prevent from multiply same request if you, for example, faslty reentering to application.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I always had a feeling this would come into play sometime just havn't got to round to implementing it. I think its time! :) thanks for this it seems to work fine. This will make the app more robust. Im calling it as mark based on the fact that anyone else see this, they will implement it even if it doesn't fix my issue (Which by the looks of it, it has). Thanks again